# Flutter : how to change automatically from splash screen to next screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc, flutter-go-router

I'm having an issue with moving from the splash screen to the next screen in my application. When the app first starts, I want to display a splash screen, and after that I try to use pushReplacement to go from the splash screen to the next screen.

How to implement this method correctly?

-route

```
GoRouter goRouter(AuthBloc authBloc) {
  return GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    routes: <GoRoute>[
      GoRoute(
          path: '/',
          name: 'intitial',
          builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
          routes: <GoRoute>[
            GoRoute(
                path: '/login',
                name: 'login',
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return const LoginPage();
                }),
            GoRoute(
              path: '/homepage',
              name: 'homepage',
              builder: (context, state) {
                return BlocProvider<WeatherBloc>(
                  create: (context) => WeatherBloc(),
                  child: MyHomepage(dateTime: DateTime.now()),
                );
              },
              routes: [
                GoRoute(
                    path: '/gempa',
                    name: 'gempa',
                    builder: (context, state) {
                      return BlocProvider<GempaBloc>(
                        create: (context) => GempaBloc(),
                        child: const GempaPage(),
                      );
                    })
              ],
            )
          ],
          redirect: (context, state) async {
            bool islogin = true;
            bool hastoken = await authBloc.firebaseAuthService.hasToken();
            return hastoken && islogin ? AppRoute.homepage : AppRoute.login;
          }),
    ],
  );
}
```

-main

```
void main(List<String> args) async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // await dotenv.load();
  Bloc.observer = Observer();
  // await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseAuthService firebaseAuthService = FirebaseAuthService();
  final AuthBloc authBloc = AuthBloc(FirebaseAuthService());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) =>
          AuthBloc(firebaseAuthService)..add(CheckSignStatus()),
      child: BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is AuthUser) {
            context.go(AppRoute.homepage);
          } else if (state is NonAuthUser) {
            context.go(AppRoute.login);
          }
        },
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          title: 'sample',
          routerConfig: goRouter(authBloc),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeData(
            textTheme:
                GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've read the documentation, but I'm still confused

Comment: this might help. https://pmatatias.medium.com/how-to-handle-and-share-login-state-with-provider-in-flutter-app-5c97c00500a4

use `FutureBuilder` in your initial page

Comment: ah, i forget, thanks,that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add Future.delay for time you need for showing splash screen and navigate to other screen. Below code is for manually if you want to add splash screen but through **[flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)** you can generate your own splash screen.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, R.onBoarding);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBackground(
        child: Center(
          child: Image.asset(
            ImagesAsset.appLogo,
            height: 55.h,
            width: 245.w,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the simple way to acheive splashscreen to next page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _navigateToNextScreen();
  }

  _navigateToNextScreen() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2)); // Change 2 to the desired duration
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NextScreen()),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Splash Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NextScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Next Screen'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```